# Assigning a parameter in a JSF composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to pass values into a backing bean via a JSF composite component.  So if I have an interface like this

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="commentList"/>
</composite:interface>
```

Can I then assign the value of commentList to a backing bean to do some processing on it?

Bonus question:  Can I create a bean localized to this component?  Ie, is there a way to create a bean such that it doesn't conflict with other instance of this components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a so-called backing component which you bind via `componentType` attribute:

```
<composite:interface componentType="someComposite">
```

With

```
@FacesComponent("someComposite")
public class SomeComposite extends UINamingContainer {
    // ...
}
```

Yes, each composite instance will obviously have its own backing component instance.

Here are some more concrete real world examples:

- [Our `[composite-component]` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info)
- [How to prevent multiple composite components reset themselves on a JSF page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702370/how-to-prevent-multiple-composite-components-reset-themselves-on-a-jsf-page/13703438#13703438)
- [How to implement a dynamic list with a JSF 2.0 Composite Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358066/how-to-implement-a-dynamic-list-with-a-jsf-2-0-composite-component/6358272#6358272)