# JSF <ui:repeat> <c:forEach> composite UINamingContainer

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, custom-component

Basically, I want to iterate over a list of properties to render a list of components.
I'm using a component-type of the UIComponent because I need a separate scope for each component. The component works, but I don't know how to give it parameters from the list.

Here is a simple test :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h:outputText value="test"/>
        <h:outputLabel value=" : "/>
        <bf:testA service="test"/>
        <h:outputLabel value=" : "/>
        <bf:testB service="test"/>
    </li>
    <c:forEach items='#{serviceList.val}' var="serviceval">
        <li>
            <h:outputText value="#{serviceval}"/>
            <h:outputLabel value=" : "/>
            <bf:testA service="#{serviceval}"/>
            <h:outputLabel value=" : "/>
            <bf:testB service="#{serviceval}"/>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
    <ui:repeat value="#{serviceList.val}" var="serviceval">
        <li>
            <h:outputText value="#{serviceval}"/>
            <h:outputLabel value=" : "/>
            <bf:testA service="#{serviceval}"/>
            <h:outputLabel value=" : "/>
            <bf:testB service="#{serviceval}"/>
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

Bellow testA which works :

```
<c:interface>
    <c:attribute name="service" />
</c:interface>

<c:implementation>
    <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.service}"/>
</c:implementation>
```

and testB which doesn't :

```
<c:interface componentType="testBComponent">
    <c:attribute name="service" />
</c:interface>

<c:implementation>
    <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.service}"/>
</c:implementation>
```

I need testB because it uses the component-type.

My TestBComponent is just a simple POJO for this test :

```
@FacesComponent(value="testBComponent")
public class TestBComponent extends UINamingContainer
{
    private String service;
    public TestBComponent()
    {
        service = "Failed";
    }

    public String getService()
    {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(String service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Here are the results :

- test : test : test
- test1 : test1 : Failed
- test2 : test2 : Failed
- test3 : test3 : Failed
- test1 : test1 : Failed
- test2 : test2 : Failed
- test3 : test3 : Failed

Tested on Tomcat 8 with :
jsf-myfaces : 2.1.13
jsf-mojarra : 2.2.4

I'm having a hard time finding documentation about build and render time with composites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not taking care of the component's state.

Use `StateHelper` as available by the inherited `getStateHelper()` method.

```
@FacesComponent(value="testBComponent")
public class TestBComponent extends UINamingContainer {

    public TestBComponent() {
        setService("Failed");
    }

    public String getService() {
        return (String) getStateHelper().eval("service");
    }

    public void setService(String service) {
        getStateHelper().put("service", service);
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [How to save state when extending UIComponentBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405278/how-to-save-state-when-extending-uicomponentbase/9406707#9406707)
- [How to prevent multiple composite components reset themselves on a JSF page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702370/how-to-prevent-multiple-composite-components-reset-themselves-on-a-jsf-page/13703438#13703438)

Comment: No local variables in a custom component, got it ! Thanks.

Comment: You may have, but they won't be saved in JSF view state. They will only be component instance scoped "the usual Java way". Component instances are created during every restore/build view.